# How do I get a web control's HTML?

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, webforms, stringbuilder

i am working with String Builder and a Tree view control which i am generating Dynamically in my page.

This is what i have tried with :

```
Public sbMenu As New StringBuilder
```

In Page Load Event

```
    Dim TreeView1 As New TreeView()
    TreeView1.ID = "tree1"
    TreeView1.ShowCheckBoxes = TreeNodeTypes.All
    TreeView1.ShowLines = True
    TreeView1.Nodes.Clear()
```

I am loading the TreeView1 using Database data and atlast appending to my string builser object as

```
    sbMenu.Append("<div>")
    sbMenu.Append(TreeView1)
    sbMenu.Append("</div>")
```

But the sbMenu doesn't contain the TreeView1 instead it is storing

```
System.Web.UI.WebControls.TreeView
```

Can you please help me , By how my stringBuilder can hold the TreeView control and can make use of it..

I will use this in my .aspx page as

```
<%= sbMenu.Tostring() %>
```

here i need the TreeView control..

Comment: What do you *expect* that the string value of a `TreeView` should be? By default, when you call `ToString()` on an object, it returns the fully qualified name of the class.

Comment: I need the StringBuilder to hold the TreeView control and I can use that in my .aspx page as <%= sbMenu.ToString()%> so that there i can get a Tree View

Comment: Do you really even need to dynamically add the TreeView? Why not just put the control in the page, add the data from the code-behind, and hide it if you don't need it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a control's HTML by calling `RenderControl`. E.g.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();

using (var sw = new StringWriter(sb)) 
using (var writer = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
{
     myControl.RenderControl(writer);
}

string html = sb.ToString();
```

Or in VB:

```
Dim sb = New StringBuilder()

Using sw As New StringWriter(sb)
    Using writer As New HtmlTextWriter(sw)
        myControl.RenderControl(writer)
    End Using
End Using

Dim html As String = sb.ToString()
```

Comment: @MikeSmithDev Updated with VB .NET version.